# Why inline-block container cause scrollbars on auto overflow?

Tags: html, overflow, css

This is a very simple case:

http://jsfiddle.net/8j6rt02h/

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer-inlineBlock">
        <div class="content">            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outerContainer{
   width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.innerContainer-inlineBlock{
    display: inline-block;
}
.content{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

The outer container is having auto overflow while the inner container is having inline-block display. Then even if the content size is the same or even a little bit smaller than the containers, the scrollbars still show.

If I use block display for the inner container, it behaves as expected.

I have tried on both Chrome and IE, both have this issue.

Anyone can give a little bit explanation?

Answer (score 6):

The inner container, being an inline-block, sits on a baseline which is raised slightly above the bottom edge of the outer container (to make room for [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)). Since the outer container is exactly the same height as the inner container, there isn't enough space to accommodate the area below the baseline, resulting in overflow.

Changing the inner container to a block does away with the baseline entirely, because there is no other inline content.

Answer (score -1):

`inline-block` elements have margins on them so causing that scrollbar to appear. If you set `-4px` margin on them you won't see the scrollbar.

```
.innerContainer-inlineBlock{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -2px;/*left and right -2-2=-4px*/
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8j6rt02h/2/)

If you consider using float instead of inline-block then you won't see the scrollbar because there is no margin space on them. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8j6rt02h/3/)

Comment: No I don't think so, if you add that -2 margin, it actually shrinks the size of the content to 96px. In your demo, you can see the sizes of above and below boxes are not the same.

Comment: "inline-block elements have margins on them" No, they don't. Why would you set the margins to -2px and not 0 otherwise?

Comment: Just put two inline-block divs in one line then you'll see what I mean and why used -2px. To remove between those two inline-block elements you need -4px to remove those space....

Comment: That's not margins. That's something else.

Comment: I would be glad to know that else. Anyway setting negative margin behaves like you floated div without spaces between them...

Comment: Usually it'll be the whitespace between them, but this should not happen if you did put them on the same line - it will only happen when you have them on different lines. In the case of this question, though, it's not whitespace. It's the baseline, as I stated in my answer.