# Unnecessary scrollbars appear for inline-block

Tags: html, css, user-interface

While I was coding a website, I happened to stumble upon something peculiar.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id='a'><div id='b'></div></div>
```

CSS

```
html{height:100%}
body
{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    padding: 0 5%;
}
#a
{
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
#b
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And a JSFiddle, just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/ud3y1vh2/

The problem is that an unnecessary vertical scrollbar appears, even though none of the elements supposedly overflow. I'm familiar with the regular two-inline-blocks-next-to-eachother problem that causes whitespace to appear between the elements, but this seems to be a bit tougher nut to crack.

What I've thought of:

- Removing any and all whitespace in the HTML
- `overflow:hidden` on `#a` - Works, but can't be used for my website (user has to be able to scroll the content when needed)
- `font-size:0` on `#a` - Works, but can't be used, since my website uses `em`s for sizing `#a` and other elements. Not a viable solution for me.
- Making `#b` a block-type element, or lowering it's height - Works, but not viable for my website.

So if you can come up with any ideas on how to remove the scrollbar (or rather, remove the *cause* of the scrollbar), I'd like to hear them.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613967/why-inline-block-container-cause-scrollbars-on-auto-overflow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scrollbar can be removed by changing the `vertical-align` property of the `inline-block` element to a value such as `top`. The [default `vertical-align` value is `baseline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align), which is why the element is being aligned to the bottom (resulting in a scrollbar)..

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2aqmmohr/)

```
#b {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Frustratingly simple. Thank you.